# xcode All-in-one layout: keyboard shortcut to switch between project and debug page?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

When you configure xcode to use the All-in-one layout, a toggle appears to allow you to switch between project and debug 'mode' (the IDE calls these pages).

Is there a keyboard shortcut to perform the toggle?

Comment: I've been searching in vain for exactly this for a while now.. hopefully someone here can help us out!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Project: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> (zero)
- Build: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- Debug: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>

Found this here: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/252986-keyboard-shortcut-for-next-page-in-all-in-one-layout.html

More shortcuts:
http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2008/02/complete-xcode-keyboard-shortcut-list.html

Comment: does not feel very consistent, but it works :) I notice that Cmd-0 switches focus between panes once on the Project page, but skips the editor. Is there a shortcut to set the focus to the editor pane?

Answer (score 6):

I use (discovered)
<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>

using all in one setup

Comment: that is for switching between open windows.