# Quickly switch between the project and debug windows in Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts, project

When I run a program in the Simulator, the project window changes to the debug window automatically. This is what I want it to do. However, after running the simulation, I want to get back to the project window. I have to use my mouse to click on the tiny icon on the top left of the debug window in order to get to the project window again. Is there a faster way to do this, like maybe a keyboard shortcut, or a setting that can be changed so that the window automatically changes after the simulation finishes?

Comment: It's two months later, but in case you're still curious, the question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210708/xcode-all-in-one-layout-keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-project-and-debug-pa

Comment: Cmd-0 was what I was looking for. Wish there was an easier shortcut.

Comment: It's easily customized. I changed mine to be Cmd-1 and Cmd2... it became second nature after a day or so.

Answer (score 0):

Download Xcode 4. It's much better: all in one window, no more window management hassles.

Comment: I downloaded that and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Also you lose all the great keyboard shortcuts that were available in XCode 3.

Answer (score 0):

I use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to close the frontmost window (unless it's my project window already).